# Gcloud clone do not use correct account

Tags: linux, git, google-cloud-platform

I try to clone a repository from gcloud.

Here is my configuration:

```
$ gcloud info
Google Cloud SDK [183.0.0]

Platform: [Linux, x86_64] ('Linux', 'debian', '4.9.0-4-amd64', '#1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3 (2017-12-03)', 'x86_64', '')
Python Version: [2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]]
Python Location: [/usr/bin/python2]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2017.12.08]
  app-engine-python: [1.9.64]
  beta: [2017.12.08]
  gsutil: [4.28]
  bq: [2.0.27]
  alpha: [2017.12.08]
System PATH: [/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games]
Python PATH: [/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib:/usr/lib/python2.7:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [False]
Kubectl on PATH: [/usr/bin/kubectl]

Installation Properties: [/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/home/me/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [default]
Active Configuration Path: [/home/me/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default]

Account: [account@client.com]
Project: [ipcloud-viewer]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [ipcloud-viewer]
    account: [account@client.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [True]
  [compute]
    region: [europe-west1]
    zone: [europe-west1-d]

Logs Directory: [/home/me/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/home/me/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.12.21/11.39.49.435511.log]

git: [git version 2.11.0]
ssh: [OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u2, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017]
```

But when I whant to clone I've got this:

```
$ gcloud source repos clone repo --project=client_project --account=account@client.com
Clonage dans '/home/me/project/temp/repo'...
fatal: remote error: Access denied to me@other.fr
ERROR: (gcloud.source.repos.clone) Command '['git', 'clone', u'https://source.developers.google.com/p/client_project/r/repo', '/home/me/project/temp/repo', '--config', 'credential.helper=!gcloud auth git-helper --account=account@client.com --ignore-unknown $@']' returned non-zero exit status 128
```

As you can see, I'm logged with `account@client.com` and during the process, the account `me@other.fr` is used... and I do not know why !

Any idea what is the problem ?

BTW, I delete my `~/.config/gcloud` and redone a `gcloud init` before doing all this....

---

EDIT: solution founded.

I had a `~/.netrc` file information about mu `me@other.fr` account... I removed it and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that the original repository (the one you're trying to clone) has `me@other.fr` as owner, but you're trying to access it (via git, under the hood) using the `account@client.com` account - the gcloud command executes under a single account.

You could try to add the `account@client.com` account as a project member of the original project, allowing it to access that private repository for cloning, see [Adding project members and setting permissions](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories#adding_project_members_and_setting_permissions).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.

But it's the opposite, the project is created by the client (and he gave me an account to use with his own dns witch is account@client.com).

What I do not get, is why gcloud try to use my personnal account (me@other.fr). And obviously, I can not ask the client to add my personal account to the project.